# Call another class and putting stuff in the constructor

Tags: php, wordpress, class, constructor

I think I'm having trouble understanding the constructor in a class. I have written a class within a wordpress plugin. I now want to use that class in another plugin. This is all fine. Within my function I can do new class blah blah then do my thing. However what I want to be able to do is pass some values into this new classes constructor file and then pass the variables from the constructor. Sooooooooooo something like:

```
class why_wont_you_work {

public foo1;
public foo2;

public function __construct() { 

     $this->foo1= $otherclassfunction['name'];
     $this->foo2= $otherclassfunction['address'];

public function do_stuff() {

    $otherclass = new $otherclass;
    $otherclassfunction = $otherclass->otherclassfunction();

    echo $this->foo1;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a constructor that accepts arguments, and pass them from where you create them, just like normal for a function.

```
class why_wont_you_work {

public foo1;
public foo2;

public function __construct($name, $address) { 

     $this->foo1= $name;
     $this->foo2= $address;

public function do_stuff() {

    $otherclass = new $otherclass;
    $otherclassfunction = $otherclass->otherclassfunction();

    echo $this->foo1;

}


$obj = new why_wont_you_work( "some name", "some address" );
```